# Dynamically change Tweet Button "data-text" contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, twitter

This question comes very closely to what I'm after: [Replace an Attribute in the Tweet Button with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571115/replace-an-attribute-in-the-tweet-button-with-jquery)

However, [the suggested solution](http://jsfiddle.net/45ddY/) works just once. That is, I cannot use it in my *switch* statement like this:

```
    switch(element.id)
    {
        case "t1":
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('a[data-text]').each(function(){
                    $(this).attr('data-text', Text_Variant_1);
                });
                $.getScript('http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js');
            });
            break;
        case "t2":
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('a[data-text]').each(function(){
                    $(this).attr('data-text', Text_Variant_2);
                });
                $.getScript('http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js');
            });
        ...
    }
```

What happens is that the *data-text* attribute is set according to whichever case happens first and doesn't change afterwards.

How can I change *data-text* attribute of a Tweet Button as many times as I need?

**Update:** here's the page I'm working on: http://zhilkin.com/socio/en/

The *Traits* table can be safely ignored. What I want to do with the *Sociotypes* table is that when you click on a type, the *data-text* of the Tweet Button below the description on the right should be changed accordingly.

Right now it works like this: if I hover on or click "Don Quixote", then *data-text* is set to "... Don Quixote ...", and it stays the same if I click "Dumas" later. And vice versa: if I hover on or click "Dumas", then *data-text* is set to "... Dumas ..." and doesn't change if I click "Don Quixote". (Other types are empty at the moment.)

So, the Tweet Button is only changed the first time I run the script, but I need it to be updated as many times as the type changes.

Comment: What's the `switch` variable? Can yo post some more relevant code? Also why is `"2"` in quotes and `1` no quotes? Your prolbem might be there...

Comment: The switch variable is a hovered-on element. According to which of the elements is hovered on, I'd like to set the data-text attribute of the Tweet Button. The switch statement works (I'm using it for other stuff, too), but I can't use it to change data-text several times (it's set only once and then doesn't change).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I struggled with this for a couple of hours this morning, but finally got it working!  The problem is essentially that you can only include the twitter *widgets.js* script **once** in the page, and that script evaluates the `data-text` attribute on load. Therefore, in your example, you dynamically set the `data-text` attribute **before** loading the script, which will work as expected. However, you can then make no further updates as the script has already run.

I saw [**this article**](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/2326) suggesting you can call `twttr.widgets.load()` again at runtime to re-evaluate and re-render the buttons, however that didn't work for me. This is because that function re-evaluates `<a>` tags, not `<iframe>` tags!

So the solution, as [**pointed out here**](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/890), is to completely remove the rendered `<iframe>` from the DOM, then make a new `<a>` element with all the appropriate attributes before calling `twttr.widgets.load()` to finally re-evaluate it and turn it into an `<iframe>`.

Please see [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/chris27/DQw5b/4/) for a working example!

Comment: Looks exactly like what I need. Will try to implement this solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Works! but the Firefox and Chrome are blocking the popup :(

Adding this will avoid the blocking:

onclick="return !window.open(this.href, 'tweet', 'menubar=no')"

Comment: this is nice but twitter ahref blinks

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Twitter's [createShareButton](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/javascript-create) API call:

```
function callAsRequired(){
  var nodeID = 'YourTwitterNodeID'
  
  //Remove existing share button, if it exists.
  var myNode = document.getElementById(nodeID);
  while (myNode.firstChild) {
    myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
  }

  //Create button and customise
  twttr.widgets.createShareButton(
    'http://your.custom.url.here/',
    document.getElementById(nodeID),
    {
      count: 'none',
      text: 'Your custom tweet here'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are using `each` loop you can use `if` statements instead:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
       $('a[data-text]').each(function(){
          if (theCase == 1) {
             $(this).attr('data-text', Text_Variant_1);
          }
          else if (theCase == 2) { ... }
        })
 });
```

Comment: I don't think using if/else instead of switch would change anything. Whichever case occurs first (can be "t1", can be "t2", etc.), data-text is set to the corresponding value and then doesn't change again (if another case occurs).

Comment: it's better to see the markup, i think you should use another method for achieving desired result.

Comment: I've added a link to the live page and a brief explanation of what's going on. Hope it helps!