# Changing the value of data-text attribute of the Twitter button dynamically based on input data from an API using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I designed a page, where clicking on the button "Get Quote" will display various quotes in a div, which are obtained from an API. I want to add a twitter shate button. But I am really confused on how to change the value of the "data-text" attribute of the twitter button, dynamically which the changing values of the quotes from the API. I use jQuery for processing data from the API, so how do I change the value of the "data-text" using jQuery?

The code is:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <h1><div id="quotegot" class="well well-lg quote"></div></h1>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="quoteid">Get Quote</button>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false" data-text="hello">Tweet</a><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$("#quoteid").on("click",function(){
    $.getJSON("http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&key=457653&format=json&lang=en",function(quotejson){
        $("#quotegot").html(quotejson["quoteText"]);
    });
});
$(".twitter-share-button").attr("data-text", $(".quote").text());
```

Comment: Please provide the code you have now (i.e. the code that processes the API data)

Answer (score 0):

[Dynamically change Tweet Button "data-text" contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486354/dynamically-change-tweet-button-data-text-contents)

Can't comment yet so putting it here.  There is a jsfiddle in there showing how it works.